# Redis Cluster or Replication without proxy

Tags: redis

Is it possible to build one master (port 6378) + two slave (read only port: 6379, 6380) "cluster" on one machine and increase the performances (especially reading) and do not use any proxy? Can the site or code connect to master instance and read data from read-only nodes? Or if I use 3 instances of Redis I have to use proxy anyway?

Edit: Seems like slave nodes don't have any data, they try to redirect to master instance, but it is not correct way, am I right?

Comment: Why slave nodes can not answer data? Why it redirect to master node? (error) MOVED 9686 127.0.0.1:6378

Comment: Please use the "edit" instead of a comment if you want to add something to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely. You can code the paths in your app so writes and reads go to different servers. Depending on the programming language that you're using and the Redis client, this may be easier or harder to achieve.

Edit: that said, I'm unsure how you're running a cluster with a single master - the minimum should be 3.

Comment: Thanks, I try it, and get I (error) MOVED 9686 127.0.0.1:6378. Why my read-only instances can not return me a data by itself? Why do it need to redirect request to master instance?

Comment: Actually the 3-masters check is done in the Ruby script so technically you could have a Redis cluster with only 1 or 2 masters. I have a [Python tool](https://github.com/projecteru/redis-trib.py) which allows that.

Comment: You hacker you @neuront :)

Comment: I don't know exactly, but for build it, get info and so on I use command cluster. But actually it seems like replication.                                              _PS D:\Programms\Redis-x64-3.2.100> .\redis-cli.exe -h redis -p 6378 cluster nodes
'first big number' 127.0.0.1:6376 slave 'master node number' 0 1517815038188 2 connected
'master node number' 127.0.0.1:6378 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected 0-16383
'second big number' 127.0.0.1:6377 slave 'master node number' 0 1517815039282 1 connected_

Comment: In code I add SET to fist-master ip:port instance, GET to one of slave ip:port, but I still get (error) MOVED 9686 127.0.0.1:6378. I don't understand something =( .

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a [`READONLY`](https://redis.io/commands/readonly) command after connecting to the slave before you could execute any read commands.

A `READONLY` command only affects during the current socket session which means you need this command for every TCP connection.